# How do I remove slash at the end of the URL on Typo3-9.5.14

Tags: typo3, url-routing, nginx-config, typo3-9.x

We are using Typo3 9.5 on NGINX server. We are experiencing strange problem. When we are accessing a page from our Menubar, it is giving error 404, but if we remove the slash at the end of the page then it is working fine. You can check it here:

http://staging.venicexplorer.net/grids-1/one-column/  - Giving error 404.

http://staging.venicexplorer.net/grids-1/one-column   - Working fine.

Can anyone please let us know how could we solve this problem?

Thanks
Prasun

Comment: I am not aware of this problem - URLs with Slash giving 404. It is not reproducible with standard out of the box TYPO3 installation, AFAIK. Can you add more information?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the trailing slash to TYPO3 with the PageType enhancer. See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86160-PageTypeEnhancerForMappingTypeParameter.html :

```
routeEnhancers:
  AddTrailingSlash:
    type: PageType
    default: /
    index: ''
    map:
      /: 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to remove the trailing slash and not adding. Can you please let me know how can I remove the slash at the end of URL

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the URLs without the trailing slash cause problems on your site. This should not happen out of the box.

In any case, I think it is preferable to have one canonical URL so I would redirect the ones without trailing slash to trailing slash or the other way around.

Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?typo3/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=307]
```

Nginx:

```
location ~ /?typo3/ {
}

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/?(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
  }
}
```

---

Notes:

- **Please be careful with this and do it on a test site first** - internally there is a redirect from /typo3 to /typo3/ - if you redirect all with trailing slash to non trailing slash you can break things. That is why I added the exception in the second line. I do not know if there are other cases on your site where this might break existing URLs.
- I always start my rewrites with ^/? - this is only relevant for Apache: This means they will work with starting slash and without - this is due to the fact the passed URLs differ between .htaccess and rules in apache config - the way I do it, the rule will work in both.
- You might also be able to do this in TYPO3 - I prefer to do general redirects in the webserver configuration.

---

Related issue:

- [Redirect URLs with trailing slashes to their canonical non-trailing-slash URL (or the other way around)](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89552)